# When I am importing pypsa module in Spyder IDE, I am getting this error, could you please someone sort out this?

Tags: pypsa

When I am importing pypsa module in spyder IDE, I got this follwing error, and please help me how to sort out this issue?

import pypsa
Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In[1], line 1
import pypsa

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pypsa_*init*_.py:8
from pypsa import (

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pypsa\components.py:37
from pypsa.io import (

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pypsa\io.py:30
import xarray as xr

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray_*init*_.py:1
from xarray import testing, tutorial

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\testing.py:10
from xarray.core import duck_array_ops, formatting, utils

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\duck_array_ops.py:36
from xarray.core import dask_array_ops, dtypes, nputils

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dask_array_ops.py:3
from xarray.core import dtypes, nputils

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dtypes.py:7
from xarray.core import utils

File ~\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\xarray\core\utils.py:443
class Frozen(Mapping[K, V]):

TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to xarray not to pypsa. You could try to uninstall/install or update xarray.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).